# Cloudpage click tracking implementation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Are there any resources on tracking clicks on a cloudpage? From all I can gather, this type of functionality would require web analytics connector, since clicks are not tracked in the activity tab, just cloudpage views, is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 2024:**
I have created a quite simple solution, allowing you to track clicks on Cloud Pages using a combination of SSJS/Ampscript and jQuery. It is quite easy to implement: https://digitalmarketingoncloud.com/salesforce-marketing-cloud/tracking-clicks-on-outbound-links-from-cloud-pages/

It will automatically add an onclick listener to all href links, and store information about the clicked link, along with subscriber key and other attributes

---

Well - outbound clicks (which I assume is what you want to track) are normally not counted on any website, also not on CloudPages. Implementing Web Analytics Connector (WAC) will not provide you with any functionality in this context, as it is intended to append e.g. UTM parameters to links in emails.

You will not be able to view CloudPage clicks by any of the features available in SFMC, as this requires a custom solution. Generally speaking, you must have a setup similar to email click tracking, which replaces the URL with a tracking URL, and once the click is recorded on the tracking domain, the visitor is redirected to the original URL.

You could *theoretically* build this tracking solution using CloudPages/Code Resources, where clicks are stored in a data extension - but it will require a high level of customisation, especially when adding tracked links to future CloudPages.

If you want to track traffic originating from CloudPages on 3rd party sites, you must manually add UTM parameters to your links, since as I mentioned before, WAC is only available for emails.

Comment: Thank you Lukas. Looking back at my question, I should've mentioned tracking web activity from links as opposed to the clicks. Would that still be mostly handled outside of SFMC with google analytics and such?

Comment: Exactly - I have updated my answer to reflect it

Comment: It is always a pleasure to read your posts Lukas ;)

Comment: Thank you, @JohannesSchapdick - happy to share some knowledge with the community